# $\{a=c_0 , c_1 ,... \}$ be an infinite partition of $[a,b]$; in each $[c_i,c_{i+1}]$ , $f$ is integrable ; then is $f$ integrable in $[a,b]$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be a real valued function on a closed bounded interval $[a,b]$ and $\{a=c_0 , c_1 ,... \}$ be an infinite partition of $[a,b]$ such that in each interval $[c_i,c_{i+1}]$ , $f$ is integrable ; then is $f$ integrable in $[a,b]$ ?

Comment: Is more known about $f$, e.g. is $f$ continuous? Edit: while $f$ being continuous would make it obviously easy to answer...any other properties?

Comment: @Hirshy : If $f$ were continuous on whole $[a,b]$ , then its trivial ...

Comment: yeah, I realised that just when I hit "Add comment"...

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by an infinite partition? I'd guess from context an infinite partition of the intervall $[0,1]$ would be $c_i=1-\frac{1}{i}$?

Comment: The answer from @JohnBentin is good. Is there a counter-example in which the sum of the integrals over all the individual partitions converges, but the function is still not integrable? Let's say Riemann integrable. My guess is no?

Comment: The Heine-Borel theorem implies that there is no such thing as an "infinite partition" of a compact interval--for example, the partition $[c_i,c_{i+1})$ where $c_i=1-1/i$, is an infinite partition of $[0,1)$, not $[0,1]$. Indeed, as soon as you include a subinterval of $[0,1]$ which contains $1$, you've now made all but finitely many of these intervals redundant.

Comment: @Ian that's a fair point. In which case, the answer is clearly that f is integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a=0,\,b=1,\,c_i=1-1/(i+1)$ for $i=1,2,...$, and $$f(x)=\frac1{(1-x)^2}\sin \frac\pi{1-x}\quad\text{for}\quad 0\leqslant x<1,$$ with $f(1)=0.$ Then $f$ is integrable on each $[c_i\,,c_{i+1}]$ $(i=0,1,...)$, and $\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ exists for all $x<1$, but $f$ is not integrable on $[0\,,1]$.

Comment: Even simpler, $1/x$ on [0,1] with partitions $c_i=\frac{1}{i}$.

Comment: @JahanClaes: For the $[c_i\,,c_{i+1}]$ to be nontrivial, we need to have each $c_i<c_{i+1}$; and your function isn't integrable on $[c_0\,,c_1]$. I preferred to have a uniform bound to the integral on any subinterval, although this wasn't specified, so my example is more complicated than necessary .

Comment: That's fair! And let's say my intervals go like $[c_{i+1},c_i]$, or something. And for the record, my indexing starts from 1, and my function is certainly integrable on every interval.

Comment: @JohnBentin   Just make it $1/(1-x)$ then, with your $c_i.$