# Another question on bounded function , infinite partition and integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am looking for an example of a bounded real valued function $f$ on some closed bounded interval $[a,b]$ such that for some infinite partition $\{a=c_0 , c_,c_2 , ...\}$ of $[a,b]$ , $f$ is Riemann integrable on each $[c_i , c_{i+1}]$ but $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ ? Also , can we produce an example where the sum of the integrals over the intervals $[c_i,c_{i+1}]$ converges , but $f$ is still not Riemann integrable ? ( continuation of [$\{a=c_0 , c_1 ,... \}$ be an infinite partition of $[a,b]$; in each $[c_i,c_{i+1}]$ , $f$ is integrable ; then is $f$ integrable in $[a,b]$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402915/a-c-0-c-1-be-an-infinite-partition-of-a-b-in-each-c-i-c-i) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M = \sup_{[a,b]}|f|.$ Since $f$ is bounded, $M<\infty.$

We have $a= c_0 < c_1 < \cdots \to b.$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ Choose $n$ such that $b-c_n < \epsilon.$ Then there are partitions $P_k$ of $I_k=[c_{k-1},c_k], k = 1,\dots , n,$ such that the upper minus the lower Darboux sum of $f$ on each $I_k$ is less than $\epsilon/n.$ Let $P=P_1 \cup \cdots \cup P_n \cup \{b\};$ then $P$ is a partition of $[a,b].$  Relative to the partition $P,$ the upper minus the lower Darboux sum is less than $$n(\epsilon/n) +2M(b-c_n) = \epsilon + 2M\epsilon.$$ That shows $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b].$

Answer (score 1):

The Riemann—Lebesgue theorem says that a bounded function on $[a,b]$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if its set of discontinuity points is of measure zero. Note that your assumption implies that this criterion is satisfied, since the union of countably many sets of measure zero is a set of measure zero. Hence there are no counterexamples.